# Hide remote notification at specific viewcontroller when app is in foreground in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, push-notification, swift4

I am using firebase notifications in my chat app and I am getting it to my device.My question is how to hide remote notification at the particular view controller.when the app is in the foreground I am using

> UNUserNotificationCenter, will present delegate method

to display the banner but when I am in chatViewController I don't want to show the notification banner, sound, alert like whats app feature I want..Sorry for my English

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    let userInfo:[AnyHashable:Any] =  notification.request.content.userInfo
    print("\(userInfo)")

    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

Comment: Look at all the values of `UNNotificationPresentationOptions`. There should be one `.none` (`UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone` in Objective-C). to use in the `completionHandler()` when you decide that you don't want to show it. But then, it's another question to know which ViewController is currently presented to the user (and depends on your app architecture).

Comment: So in pseudo code: `if showAlert {completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound]} else {completionHandler([.none])}`

Comment: @LarmeI don't want to show at particular view.Like whats app when chatting with some dont show.

Answer (score 7):

You can find current view controller using this methods:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var topViewController: UIViewController? {
        return self.topViewController(currentViewController: self)
    }

    private func topViewController(currentViewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController {
        if let tabBarController = currentViewController as? UITabBarController,
            let selectedViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController {
            return self.topViewController(currentViewController: selectedViewController)
        } else if let navigationController = currentViewController as? UINavigationController,
            let visibleViewController = navigationController.visibleViewController {
            return self.topViewController(currentViewController: visibleViewController)
       } else if let presentedViewController = currentViewController.presentedViewController {
            return self.topViewController(currentViewController: presentedViewController)
       } else {
            return currentViewController
        }
    }
}
```

And than, in `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)` add this code:

```
if self.window?.rootViewController?.topViewController is ChatViewController {
    completionHandler([])
} else {
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
```

Comment: getting error.UNNotificationPresentationOptions' has no member 'none'

Comment: I'm sorry, wrong attribute. Use `[]` instead of `.none`

Answer (score 1):

> Specify **UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone** to silence the notification completely.

[UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationpresentationoptionnone)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the empty completionHandler([]) to hide remote notification.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent 
                            notification: UNNotification, 
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: 
                            @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> 
           Void) {

let userInfo:[AnyHashable:Any] =  notification.request.content.userInfo
print("\(userInfo)")

completionHandler([])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for us-

**AppDelegate.m**

```
// Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
}
```